# Is it okay to use negative pixels in css margin value or should I do something else?

Tags: html, css

After I set a `span` tag style to `display:inline-block`, I also added a `line-height` style. The `span` tag moved down by the `line-height` value, so to move it up again, I added a `margin-top:-5px;` style to the `span` as well. Is this considered an okay practice or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check our your `vertical-align` for the `span` as well as every other element that's `inline` within the block-level parent, which could be making it drop down so far. Setting all of those to `vertical-align: middle;` could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fine. For example, negative margins are commonly used to center align elements.

Answer (score 3):

it is ok to use it but for best practice use [css transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

```
transform: translate3d(12px, 50%, 3em)
transform: translate(12px, 50%)
transform: translateX(2em)
transform: translateY(3in)
```

with transform you avoid other elements to be affected by margin.